# Formatting an integer to GBP in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to format a certain number of credits as GBP for example displaying 100 credits as £1.00 and 80 credits as £0.80. I am running python 3.5.

This is my code:

```
playerCredit = 100
print(format(playerCredit, ',.2f')) #this outputs 100.00
playerCredit = 80
print(format(playerCredit, ',.2f')) #this outputs 80.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Does that do the job?

```
playerCredit = 100
print(format(playerCredit/100., ',.2f')) 
playerCredit = 80
print(format(playerCredit/100., ',.2f'))
```

If you want to add the £ sign the following should do in Python 3.x (in 2.x you will need to encode the sign)

```
print(''.join(['£', format(playerCredit/100., ',.2f')]))
```

Comment: How would I print a £ sign before the formatted amount of credits?

Comment: Ah, apologies, forgot about the sign. Editing the answer

Comment: Doesn't matter, just saved the formatted credits as a variable and printed the pound sign and the variable on the line after, Thanks anyway.

Comment: Check my edited answer though. That's one (likely not the only one) option

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply use the format function to print the desired result.

Sample code below:

```
x=1
print('£' + format(x/100. ,',.2f'))
```

Hope this helps.